# Edit custom HTML page from WP admin dashboard

Tags: pages, html, seo, sitemap

I needed to make custom HTML page in root which will not use default wordpress theme and show content and I linked it on menu as custom links. So in front end everything perfect. But this page is not part of wordpress and I am not sure if it will harm SEO or something.

Is there any way plugin or something so text on this pages can be edited from dashboard.

Is there any way so this page to be covered with wordpress sitemap.xml, SEO settings and plugins, and chaching plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want content to be editable via the dashboard, a static HTML file is not the road you want to take.

Instead, create a [custom page template](http://codex.wordpress.org/Pages#Page_Templates), from which you call a custom header and footer.
Both [`get_header()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_header) as well as [`get_footer()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_footer) take an optional `$name` parameter to specify a specific template to call as well.

Answer (score 0):

Just make a new .php page and remove all the style attributes and includes.

For example:

http://prntscr.com/1fpi86

Then when you make a new page:

http://prntscr.com/1fpi9z

From here you just keep the content section in the .php file and build around it with a custom design